# VS2008 Installer Project: How to force "installed for everyone"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

Is there any easy way to force the option for ***installed only for this user or installed for everyone***? I want the end-user to be able to double click on the MSI file and not have to pass it command-line.

Is there an easy way to do this or will I have to inherit an installer class to customize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Click on the project, view its Properties page, set InstallAllUsers to True or False
- Right click project, go to View->User Interface
- In the User Interface page, select Installation Folder, set InstallAllUsersVisible to False.  Do this under both Install and Administrative Install

This will set the default to install all users or not, and also remove the UI option.